# Pause a program in Java and run again where it paused

Tags: java

I am creating a program in Java where I call another program to be executed.

At a particular time, suppose after 2ms I want to pause it and run another program, after executing the second one for 2ms, I want the first one to be executed where it was paused. Is there any way I can do this in Java?

Comment: `Calling another program` do you mean an external one? Another method? Running in a different thread? Is this supposed to happen synchronously? Does `Thread.sleep(2000)` solve your problem?

Comment: yes I mean an external one and I call it by the instruction below:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java process1")
It is suposed to happen synchronously but it's like round robin algorithm. Process p1 runs for 2ms then is paused and p2 runs for 2ms this is paused too ect, when there are no more processes then p1 runs again where it stoped.

Comment: Please extend your original questions with these details.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java process1")`

When you use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` you have to read from the stdout/stderr streams anyway, since otherwise the other program could hang. This is mentioned in many other Stackoverflow questions; it's a common topic.

If this is an educational assignment it's important to do it "the right way" even if you don't really need to in this particular case.

As you want to do this synchronously, you just need to `join` the 2 threads you are going to create to read from stdout and stderr.

Actually it might be even easier to just redirect stderr to stdout, then you wouldn't need multiple threads at all, and you could just read from the process' stdout in the current thread.

P.S. `ProcessBuilder` is recommended nowadays, it's supposed to be better than `Runtime.exec`.